# Javascript: how can I populate an array of property values dynamically?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of values, which I want to insert into a property of an object, but I'm not sure how.  Here's my object.  The property is called "**values**" (located at the very bottom), and as you can see, I'm trying to insert a dynamic list of data (called "**result**") into it:

```
var myConfig = {
            globals: {
                fontFamily: "Roboto"
            },
            type: "bar",
            backgroundColor: "#f4f2f2",                                
            plotarea: {
                backgroundColor: "#fff"
            },
            scaleX: {
                lineColor: "#7d7d7d",
                tick: {
                    lineColor: "#7d7d7d"
                },
                guide: {
                    visible: false
                },
                values: [result[0]["Heading"], result[1]["Heading"], result[2]["Heading"], ...],

            }};
```

Is there any way I can set this up to dynamically place this result["Heading"] data into my "values" property?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming `results` is an array of objects that have the `Heading` property, you can get an array of only those, using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, like this:

```
values: result.map(function(item){ return item.Heading; })
```

`map` is a new-ish function, defined in ECMAScript 5.1, but all major browsers support it. Basically, for every item in the array, it will execute the provided selector function, and return the result. So, you're starting with an array of objects having a `Heading` property, and ending up with an array of the `Heading` property values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Make another function to do that.

It's an Array.

You should traverse it at least once.

```
function getHeading( arr ) {
    var aa = [];
    for( var i = 0, size = arr.length ; i < size ; i++ ) {
        aa.push( arr[i].Heading );
    }
    return aa;
}
var myConfig = {
    globals: {
        fontFamily: "Roboto"
    },
    type: "bar",
    backgroundColor: "#f4f2f2",                                
    plotarea: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
    },
    scaleX: {
        lineColor: "#7d7d7d",
        tick: {
            lineColor: "#7d7d7d"
        },
        guide: {
            visible: false
        },
        values: getHeading( result ),
    }};
```